# In Angular 2 what does response.json() do?

Tags: javascript, angular

This is from angular 2 http guide for app/toh/hero.service.ts:

```
...
@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
  private heroesUrl = 'app/heroes';  // URL to web API
  constructor (private http: Http) {}
  getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || { };
  }
  private handleError (error: Response | any) {
   ...
  }

}
```

Please refer to the line let body = res.json();
From API I could not find any json() method on Response object.
From Response source I do find this:

```
export var Body = (function () {
    function Body() {
    }
    /**
     * Attempts to return body as parsed `JSON` object, or raises an exception.
     */
    Body.prototype.json = function () {
        if (isString(this._body)) {
            return Json.parse(this._body);
        }
        if (this._body instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
            return Json.parse(this.text());
        }
        return this._body;
    };
```

How these 2 are related?

Comment: What's unclear? The `.json` method tries to parse the response body into JS objects for you. It's mentioned [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#parse-to-json) that *"The Angular HTTP client follows the Fetch specification"*.

Comment: It returns the parsed data of the Response ...

Comment: @johnsharpe, Probably I have not worded my question properly.I wanted to know where in 'Response' source code I can find json() method. I find the method in 'Body' source code. I am answering my own question, please may read through it & if you find any misunderstanding on my part, please point out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked in node_modules/@angular/http/src & kept searching for

> export var Response

found that in file static_response.js. It says:

```
export var Response = (function (_super) {
__extends(Response, _super);
function Response(responseOptions) {
    _super.call(this);
    this._body = responseOptions.body;
    this.status = responseOptions.status;
    this.ok = (this.status >= 200 && this.status <= 299);
    this.statusText = responseOptions.statusText;
    this.headers = responseOptions.headers;
    this.type = responseOptions.type;
    this.url = responseOptions.url;
}
Response.prototype.toString = function () {
    return "Response with status: " + this.status + " " + this.statusText + " for URL: " + this.url;
};
return Response;
}(Body));
```

In the same file __extends is defined as follows:

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
};
```

So Body has json() & Response gets it from Body by means of copying.

Answer (score 0):

Just map your response with json()

```
this.jsonp.get("http://localhost:8080/api/getpost") 
          .map(res => res.json()) 
          .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```